# unable to load a JSON file stored locally in the System

Tags: javascript, json

I am unable to load a JSON file that is locally stored on my system. I am using the following Java Script code to load my file whenever I execute it I get the error "**Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a Feature or FeatureCollection**"

```
  var map;
  function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
  zoom: 8
  });
  }
  map.data.addGeoJson("test.geojson");
```

I tried using the following method which worked for me

```
  var map;
  function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
  zoom: 8
  });
  }

   var JSON ={"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-83.53021556073881,40.30187345365667],[-83.53021555683246,40.30177280563904],[-83.53006258934602,40.30177280901812],[-83.53006259302536,40.301873457035754],[-83.53021556073881,40.30187345365667]]]},"properties":{"stroke":"#555555","stroke-width":2,"stroke-opacity":1,"fill":"#555555","fill-opacity":0.5,"name":"Shower Test Lab","styleUrl":"#rangecolour","styleHash":"7d00d790","description":"PolygonDescription   <table border=\"3\">   </table>"}}]}

   that.map.data.addGeoJSON(JSON);
```

I had searched for it before but didn't succeed in loading it via a local file which is stored in my Eclipse SDK repository

Comment: Have you tried getJSON or Ajax

Comment: Yes I have tried using that also but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try with absolute path rather then relative path..

Comment: Do you mean the Complete Path where the File is stored C:\Users\nirmal\workspace\com.test\test.geojson"

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done by using jquery or Ajax:

jQuery:

```
 $.getJSON( "C:\Users\nirmal\workspace\com.test\test.geojson", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
   "class": "my-new-list",
   html: items.join( "" )
   }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
 dataType: "json",
 url: getAbsoluteUrl("C:\Users\nirmal\workspace\com.test\test.geojson"),
 data: data,
 success: success
});
```